# echo $USER returns root, even under non-root user

Tags: users, accounts

My main user account (sebastian) ended up [seriously crippled](https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?pid=68408) and I wanted to create a new user to look for differences, but:

- When logged in to tty as a new non-root user (e.g. guest), echo **$USER outputs root**
- Cannot login in to GUI (xfce), since all user files system seeks in `/root/` folder (where they dont exist), instead of the user folder, e.g.:

  - `/root/.bash_profile: Permission denied`
  - `/root/.config/autostart failed, ignoring: Permission denied`
  - `/root/.config/systemd/user.control, ignoring: Permission denied`
  - `/root/.config/systemd/user, ignoring: Permission denied`
  - `/root/.local/share/systemd/user, ignoring: Permission denied`
  - `Invalid XDG_CONFIG_HOME directory /root/.config, program may behave incorrectly.`
- It happens to freshly created users (such as guest), while my main user is able to log into GUI (echo $USER returns correctly the user)

Where can possibly be the problem?

- /etc/profile is default, `-rw-r--r-- root root`
- /etc/bash.bashrc is default, `-rw-r--r-- root root`
- `id`: `uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)`
- `id guest`: `uid=1002(guest) gid=1004(guest) groups=1004(guest)`
- `getent passwd guest`: `guest:x:1002:1004::/home/guest:/bin/bash`
- `echo $HOME`: `/root` (account was created by `useradd -m guest`, folder /home/guest was created automatically)
- `grep ^guest /etc/passwd`: `guest:x:1002:1004::/home/guest:/bin/bash`
- `ls -l /etc/passwd`: `-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2002 Aug 13 15:43 /etc/passwd`
- `paccheck --file-properties --quiet | grep permission`: `shadow: /usr/bin/newuidmap permission mismatch (expedted 4755)`
- Arch linux, xfce, Intel CPU/GPU

Comment: Edit your question with the output of `id`. It seems like you have setup the new user with an id of 0.

Comment: @Bib Done. Thank you for the hint, although it doesnt seem to be the case.

Comment: Give the raw output from `id`, you seem to have altered it and it does appear to show that the user has an id of 0.

Comment: Updated. Can I help any further?

Comment: Hold on. That third bullet point. Who were you logged in as? It's showing you're `root`, but I thought this question was about `guest`?

Comment: Assuming you are logged in as `guest`, then post the output of `grep ^guest /etc/passwd`. However, it may be that the shell is setuid, so whatever it is also post the `ls -l` of it.

Comment: 6th bullet point really suggests you're not actually logging in as `guest`, or you've used `sudo`, etc. to become root, or there is some other escalation that shouldn't be there

Comment: Im indeed logged in tty as guest, whoami outputs guests, however echo $USER outputs root. And I have no idea why.

Comment: @Bib No Sir, no sudo is being used. Im logged in tty2 to root account, in tty3 to guest, providing information from tty3.

Comment: I am guessing that there is a command being run which is resetting `$USER`. I would begin by checking `/etc/profile` and anything in `/etc/profile.d`.

Comment: I have compared `/etc/profile` and the contents of `/etc/profile.d` with Arco linux on my backup machine, and they seem to be identical, standard.

Comment: Exactly how are you logging in as `guest`? Could you test again, while making sure that you first log out from the `root` account?  Everything that you show indicates that you are logged in as `root`.

Comment: @Kusalananda I checked again and can confirm that I logged right after reboot to tty3 (without logging to root before) with account guest, guest password, and both $HOME and $USER variables return root instead of user. Something managing these things is probably broken.

Comment: I've resolved this only by reinstalling the system. Thank you guys for help, anyway.